# structuring code when targeting both mobile and Kinect devices

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, mobile, kinect-sdk

Building several games using Starling and the AIRKinect framework targeting Windows Kinect sensors.

I'd like to package and refactor my classes in such a way that I can easily repurpose the bulk of the code and target mobile(primarily IOS) devices.
ie touch and multitouch support would replace any AIRKinect specific skeletal tracking code.

Although I 'm coding in Actionscript 3, I think the same general code structure should remain code agnostic.

What would be a good way to structure my classes?
Which design patterns come to mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you could create an interface, like IController and several platform-dependent classes that implement that interface, for example KinectController and TouchController. Then you could check system capabilities at runtime and create either KinectController or TouchController. The usage won`t depent on concrete class as both would implement IController.

That's a very basic answer but I just cannot answer more specifically as I don`t know anything more about your project.